# jQuery Slide Down show more with slice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slice

I'm not sure why this wouldn't be working as expected since I have almost the *exact* code on another application and it's working fine.

I'm using jQuery `slice` to two show the first two elements within a div, but then when you click on `View More` it will slide down and show the next 5 elements. And it will continue until all the elements are shown and then hide the `View More` button.

So far when you load the page, it's fine. Then when you click on the `View More` it only shows then next 3 items and then just stops. Not sure if I need to set something different within the `slice` or what, but I've used this same thing on something else and it works fine.

Here's my code:
**HTML:**

```
<div class="full-list">
  <p>Item 01</p>
  <p>Item 02</p>
  <p>Item 03</p>
  <p>Item 04</p>
  <p>Item 05</p>
  <p>Item 06</p>
  <p>Item 07</p>
  <p>Item 08</p>
  <p>Item 09</p>
  <p>Item 10</p>
  <p>Item 11</p>
  <p>Item 12</p>
  <p>Item 13</p>
  <p>Item 14</p>
  <p>Item 15</p>

  <a id="viewAll" class="view-more-btn" href="#">View More</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.full-list p {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(".full-list p")
  .slice(0, 2)
  .show();
$(".full-list p:hidden").css("opacity", 0);
$("#viewAll").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".full-list p")
    .slice(0, 5)
    .slideDown("slow")
    .animate(
      {
        opacity: 1
      },
      {
        queue: false,
        duration: "slow"
      }
    );
  if ($(".full-list p").length == 0) {
    $("#viewAll").fadeOut("slow");
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Link to Demo (CodePen):** https://codepen.io/ultraloveninja/pen/Krxodj

So, I'm not sure why it would work on one thing but not on the other? I'm wondering if there is a nesting thing going on, but I've tested them targeting a specific class name and it still wasn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector for the set of hidden items needs to include the `:hidden` pseudo-class. The code you posted would only ever show the first 5 items. Please see the snippet below with `:hidden` included:

```js
$(".full-list p")
  .slice(0, 2)
  .show();
$(".full-list p:hidden").css("opacity", 0);
$("#viewAll").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".full-list p:hidden") // Added :hidden
    .slice(0, 5)
    .slideDown("slow")
    .animate(
      {
        opacity: 1
      },
      {
        queue: false,
        duration: "slow"
      }
    );
  // We need to check the count of just the hidden items
  if ($(".full-list p:hidden").length == 0) {
    $("#viewAll").fadeOut("slow");
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.full-list p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-list">
  <p>Item 01</p>
  <p>Item 02</p>
  <p>Item 03</p>
  <p>Item 04</p>
  <p>Item 05</p>
  <p>Item 06</p>
  <p>Item 07</p>
  <p>Item 08</p>
  <p>Item 09</p>
  <p>Item 10</p>
  <p>Item 11</p>
  <p>Item 12</p>
  <p>Item 13</p>
  <p>Item 14</p>
  <p>Item 15</p>

  <a id="viewAll" class="view-more-btn" href="#">View More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, heck. That makes a whole lotta sense now. I should also check the previous one too to make sure that it ok as well. Thanks!

Comment: ...and how to make the same effect but in the opposite direction? On click the button like _hideAll_ the last 5 items would be hidden, and so on.